# Human readable time parser

Tags: javascript, plugins, time, time-format

Is there any plugin for converting time in various format to integer value (seconds) that I can store in DB?

Examples:

- `"30m"` => `1800`
- `"30"` => `1800`
- `"2h"` => `7200`
- `"0.5h"` => `1800`
- `".5h"` => `1800`
- `"1"` => `60`

If there's no postfix, number should be parsed as minutes.

Comment: How is that system supposed to know the `30` is minutes, and the `1` is hours?

Comment: @Cerbrus good question. In my specific case (time tracker) it will be nice to have this condition: all strings without postfix (number only) should be interpreted as hours if number is less than 10, and as minutes if number is greater or equals 10.

Comment: So, what if you enter `10`, and want minutes? Generally, it's a bad idea to vary the functionality with obscure rules like that. Those rules don't make it easier to use.

Comment: @Cerbrus "minutes if number is greater or equals 10". So if you enter 10 it will be parsed as minutes. All numbers that are less than 10, e.g. 8 will be interpreted as hours. As to me it makes sense in time tracker, you will never track 8 minutes on any task.

Comment: Or, you could just be consistent: _"If the string contains `h`, it's read as hours, if the string contains `m`, it's read as minutes, otherwise, it's read as seconds."_

Comment: I prefer to be *user friendly* in my applications rather than *consistent*.

Comment: seconds make no sense in time tracker app.

Comment: That still leaves the ambiguity between interpreting it as minutes or hours. Changing (hidden) functionality depending on user input is _not_ "user friendly". I can guarantee you you'll get people entering "30" expecting it to result in 30 minutes.

Comment: Your app won't be user-friendly if the user has to consult the documentation because it didn't behave how it was expected to. If there aren't units, either throw an exception or use a reasonable, *consistent* default.

Comment: @Cerbrus after some reading I should agree with you about constancy. Thanks you for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
function parseToSeconds(timeString){
    var seconds = parseFloat(timeString);
    if(timeString.indexOf("m") != -1){
        seconds *= 60;
    }
    if(timeString.indexOf("h") != -1){
        seconds *= 3600;
    }
    return seconds;
}

alert("1: " + parseToSeconds("1") + "\n" +
      "1m: " + parseToSeconds("1m") + "\n" +
      "1h: " + parseToSeconds("1h") + "\n" +
      "1.5: " + parseToSeconds("1.5") + "\n" +
      "1.5m: " + parseToSeconds("1.5m") + "\n" +
      "1.5h: " + parseToSeconds("1.5h"));
```

This will convert most of your examples correctly. However, if no "format" is specified `30`, for example, it will assume the string is already in seconds.

In case you want to interpret the parameter as minutes, if there's no postfix, you can do this:

```
function parseToSeconds(timeString){
    var seconds = parseFloat(timeString);
    if(timeString.indexOf("h") != -1){
        return seconds * 3600;
    }
    return seconds * 60;
}
```

If the string contains `h`, calculate the seconds from the passed hours. Otherwise, always assume "minutes".

Comment: @limonte: I tweaked my answer a bit to allow it to parse strings missing the parameter as minutes.